# Search/indexing system for cloud based archive

Tags: search, indexing, elasticsearch

I'm involved in a project which is developing an archive system which requires an index to search documents.

The product aims to archive tens of millions of documents for very long periods (years).

CloudSearch and Solr spring to mind (the former is the one I'm most interested in).

The thing is, I suspect our requirements are in some way "easier" than most search problems, and I wondered if there was an alternative solution which would give better tradeoffs for long term archiving.

In particular:

- Our usage pattern is a lot of writes (indexes) but few reads (searches)
- Speed of searching isn't that important because these searches would be done with clear goals (e.g. digging out records for a legal case years later). For example a latency of 10 seconds might be OK. Even having "batched" searches which take an hour to fulfil might also be OK.
- We can get away with simple keyword searches. We don't need to do complex boolean queries
- The search base will be very large: We hope to have tens (hundreds?) of millions of searchable records
- Redundancy isn't *that* essential - the index isn't the canonical source of record

I understand that ElasticSearch has been successfully used for this kind of scale, but I'm just wondering if anyone can suggest an alternative which requires less resources (e.g. less servers, more compact storage requirements, easier to setup and administer etc), which balances some of these trade offs?

Any suggestions welcome!

Thanks

John

Answer (score 0):

The storage requirements and speed would require more information but we help provide the "easier to setup and administer" part.
You can try us out:
qbox.io